# Why can’t we use more than 5 tags per question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why can’t we use more than **5 tags** per question? Why is there this limitation?

Comment: If not 5 what number?  The more tags the complexity of things such as search.

Comment: Why do you think we need more? I find it quite rare that more than that would even make sense, let alone be necessary.

Comment: Even two is often too much on many many questions.

Comment: <3 the irony of this question being tagged extremely poorly. (And also not even using the 5 tags that it has.)

Comment: Because then people would put ALL THE TAGS on their questions in an attempt to get more eyes on it. Users should only tag their questions with what the question is *really* about, not with any and every tag that's even barely tangentially related to it.

Comment: Well, I agree with the points mentioned in comments, but ever since the SO introduced saving tags feature, people will save tags of their own interest.. For example a guy who is knowing `asp.net-mvc-4`, might also probably knowing `asp.net-mvc-3 or 2` etc., and he would keep seeing his own saved tag question.. I hope I made it clear with this.. Well this is indeed stupid question with poorly tagged..

Comment: Because it's less than six and greater than four.

Comment: There's an interesting discussion here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8876225#8876225 [Why is maximum number of tags on a question set to 5?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405446/3648282) - staff can use more than 5 tags.

Comment: Related bug posted on MSE from 2012: [How is it possible for a question to have more than 5 tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126455/335251)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This ensures that the most relevant tags are used, and users aren't spending a lot of time tagging unnecessary tags, tags only tangentially related to the question, tagging unrelated tags in a naive attempt to draw attention, etc.

A good question simply won't need more than 5 tags.

Comment: *"... spending a lot of time tagging unnecessary tags, tags only tangentially related to the question, tagging unrelated tags in a naive attempt to draw attention, etc."* yet somehow they manage to do so with 5 :(

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, but imagine how much worse it would be with more.

Comment: And unlimited tags means posts with every tag on the site.

Comment: *imagine how much worse* - The few questions that cynically filled things up with irrelevant tags just need to get edited; it wouldn't matter to them if the limit was a few higher.  And that's not a major concern because it's relatively rare.  Most questions with wrong tags have one or two extraneous tags that maybe seemed related to the OP but actually aren't.  Having more tag room wouldn't mean that most questions (even bad questions) would use it, in my experience.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, people with extraneous tags often only have a few *because there physically incapable of having more than that*.  You can't assert people wouldn't have added lots more if they were allowed to add more.  A *huge* percentage of questions use the limit of the number of tags, and in my experience only the first one to three are actually helpful.  If anything I'd prefer the limit to be reduced to 3 from 5.  Saying, "they just need to be edited" means wasting lots of time editing them.

Comment: I'm asserting that when I see an extraneous tag, it's *often* on a question with fewer than 5 tags.  Yes, selfish / misguided asshats that fill up the tag limit with totally irrelevant tags just to get more eyeballs would be able to add a few more, but those questions need an edit anyway (and usually a downvote) and are not in my experience very common.  (Like maybe 1 every couple weeks for an [assembly] homework questions where [python] [java] and whatnot get thrown on; is this problem much more common in relative terms for questions with only mainstream language tags, not any that I follow?)

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't agree with your assertion.  The purpose of tags isn't to add a tag for every topic that could possibly apply to a question.  Most questions don't need more than a single language tag.  A big part of the limit is there to make sure that only the most important topics are tagged to a question, it's not there (primarily) to prevent entirely irrelevant tags from being added.

Comment: Do you advocate for SO removing tags other than languages?  e.g. removing [performance], [optimization], or tags like [simd] or [x86-64]?  Read my answer for examples.  What you say makes sense for questions like "how do I X in language Y?" questions, but not for stuff where performance and/or platform-specifics in some language also matter.  There are certainly cases where more than 5 tags are relevant enough to actually tag if I could, and would help potential answerers see it depending on which set of tags they follow.

Comment: I didn't say that.  That said, I don't see value added from tags like "performance" or "optimization".  Those are meta tags, and honestly shouldn't be tags.  There's no reason to tag every performance related question with such a tag.  As for the other two you mentioned, they seem like they could be appropriate on some questions.  An architecture tag shouldn't be added to *every* question where it's used, but it'll be appropriate when a question is specifically asking about the architecture, which I'm sure exists.

Comment: I know you didn't say that, and wasn't trying to put words in your mouth, just figure out how different your stance on tags is from mine. I think [performance] is a useful tag for people to want to follow, if they want to help answer questions about why things run fast vs. slow, but don't care about helping people write general non-perf-critical code in all the languages they know.

Comment: @PeterCordes And yet you can't be an expert in "performance".  You could be an expert in performance *in a specific domain*, but that's different.  It's indicating the *form* of the question, not it's *topic*.  For more information on what a meta tag is and why it's problematic in the tag framework, search on "meta tag" as there are lots of discussions on them.

Comment: True, although I like to think I *am* an expert in performance, across a fairly decent range of categories.  (Including OS / virtual memory behaviour, how CPUs work, how to *measure* perf accurately, how C compilers work, and some about some interpreted and/or JITed languages.)  But I agree that getting a [performance] gold badge would have been possible *without* as wide knowledge, like maybe more narrowly focused on x86-64 CPUs.  (or like the way [regex] answerers sometimes have gold badges in languages they don't use / know.) That's problematic, but only if abused, which the 11 of us don't.

Comment: @PeterCordes There's still *lots* of questions that don't fall into what you've described, and I suspect plenty of questions within those areas that are still outside of your domain of knowledge.

Comment: Sure, but does a [c++] gold badge mean you know everything about c++ (or are at least familiar with all corners of the language)?  It doesn't for many people, but that's fine; with experience you know where your limitations are.

Comment: To be fair, I *don't* follow the [performance] tag because many of the questions are about languages I'm not interested in, and there's more traffic than I want to tempt myself into looking at.  I might consider adding ([c] and [performance]) to my list of tag OR tag OR tag ... filters, though, and did do that for a while as a separate search from my usual asm list of tags to watch.

Comment: _A good question simply won't need more than 5 tags_. What religion is this dogma from?

Comment: @Enlico None.  It's an assertion based on experience looking at hundreds of thousands of questions and their tags.

Comment: @Servy, really? Where did you get your experience on >= 6 tags? Maybe I'm too young of a user and don't know that once upon a time more tags were allowed? If not, then I think your knowledge of the relation between the number of tags attached to a question and whether they are suffucient is a bit skewed, at least.

Comment: @Enlico I got my experience seeing that questions didn't need more than 5 tags.  In fact my experience showed that questions didn't even need the 5 tags that they have.  What's your reasoning for why you think questions need to have more tags?  If you want to propose that questions be allowed to have more tags then first, you should be posting a new question as this question is not proposing such a change, it's asking why the behavior is what is is, and if you do make such as proposal, the burden is on *you* to show why the site would be better off with more tags on questions.

Comment: I am not saying that _all_ questions _need_ to have more than 5 tags. I'm just saying that some questions might benefit (in terms of visibility as related to what people watches which tags) from having more tags, as long as those tags are all relevant.

Comment: @Enlico If you think that that's a worthwhile proposal, then feel free to post a feature request in which you propose expanding the maximum number of tags.  You'd need to explain why you feel this is necessary and why the value added from this would be greater than the problems caused by adding it, as is described here.  As I've said, there don't seem to be questions that require more tags, certain not a lot.  If you think there are questions that do, you'd need to show that they exist and that they are significantly harmed by not having the additional tags.

Answer (score 2):

**IMO, five is occasionally not enough to cover all the reasons someone might be searching for something where a question and its answer might be useful**. **Or that people who would want to answer are following.** I often have to leave out relevant tags when editing tags on assembly / [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) / compiler questions.

I think seven might be a good number, or maybe eight, with the expectation that most questions wouldn't have that many.  Just to set a limit that's very rarely painful for legitimate uses, but still puts a cap on things for abuse.  **I'd be ok with six, but if we're going to raise it, might as well go to seven or eight just for good measure, not because I ever expect to want to use all eight.**

Having the limit at eight instead of five wouldn't make anything appreciably worse for questions that *don't* need that many.  Users who intentionally spam unrelated tags can already do that, such that an edit is needed.  Most questions with tags that don't apply have maybe one or two extra tags, like [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) on a purely assembly question; increasing the limit wouldn't make that worse.

I had a look at tags I follow for the past few days. Some of those have 5 tags, but most of those don't really need all 5. So I'm certainly not proposing to *routinely* tag more than 5. e.g. [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) is usually just filler in questions like [this with 5 tags about `std::atomic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703767/lazyarray-template-via-stdunique-ptr-is-this-a-proper-implementation-of-the-d).

The most recent one where another tag might have been relevant is [The usage of writemask k1 in AVX-512 VORPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355144/the-usage-of-writemask-k1-in-avx-512-vorps) — `x86-64 inline-assembly avx att avx512`. But that could probably just drop [avx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avx) and only keep [avx512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avx512) - masking is unique to AVX512 so the catch-all AVX isn't helping. That would make room to tag [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), or [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) (because the real question is about using masking in assembly, whether it's inline asm or not. I'll fix that now. And it's not a great example question because the inline-asm constraint / operand stuff is separable from the masking or not part.).

So it's rare to see a question where I really wish I could keep an extra tag, but it certainly happens, maybe every week or two on average.  The fact that it's not rare to see questions where five genuinely apply is a good sign that it doesn't take much to run into a case where a sixth would be nice.

**Update: [Understanding micro-architectural causes for longer code to execute 4x faster (AMD Zen 2 architecture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438609/understanding-micro-architectural-causes-for-longer-code-to-execute-4x-faster-a) needs all 5 of its tags**, and could use [sse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sse) or some of the obscure tags like [micro-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/micro-optimization).  Or less obscure like [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) which I often don't have have room to tag on questions about performance effects in compiler-generated assembly. Probably also a 7th tag like [visual-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b). Exactly the kind of question that needs lots of tags, and it just got asked minutes ago.

---

It's not at all rare for focused questions (e.g. about how GCC compiles something for x86-64 and whether that's efficient or not) to merit tags like `[c] [assembly] [x86-64] [gcc]`, leaving room for only one other tag.  (Which might be [sse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sse), [avx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avx), [simd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simd), [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance), [micro-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/micro-optimization), [inline-assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-assembly), [abi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abi), or something else. But we don't have room to pick more than 1. Your bold assertion that any question needing more tags is too broad doesn't match my experience at all.

Or if it's a question about why [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) compiles differently from GCC, there's [visual-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b) and [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) tags, along with the ISA and [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly), and the source language.

---

You could argue that maybe x86-64 should be x86-64-assembly for example, avoiding the separate [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) tag, but traditionally that's not how we do it (There are reasons to ask about x86 things separate from assembly, but often they involve low-level x86 stuff that people who follow that tag for assembly language reasons know about).

And with compilers and assembly inherently being an intersection of multiple things, that's always going to use up multiple tag slots on such questions.

Comment: If you see tags as a way to help searching, then I might agree that 5 is a bit too low. I, personally, always saw tags as a way to assign question to people willing to answer. I absolutely don't know how others see tagging. If you ask about gcc behavior, you probably need a gcc expert, maybe a c or assembly expert, but the fact that it's about 64bit can go to the question body as well, same for performance, micro-optimization, inline-assembly. google is good enough to index also the question body very well. (And I didn't vote here, because I don't know how others feel about tag usage).

Comment: @BDL: Huh?  Some people do follow tags like [inline-assembly], [micro-optimization], and [cpu-architecture].  Especially GNU C inline asm is its own thing, where you need to be an expert in it specifically to use it properly (or answer questions about using it).  Most of my "searching" on SO itself (instead of google) is for questions to answer, a tag-search sorted by activity.  It's true that *I* search on a lot of tags that tend to overlap, but some people don't include the same tags, and tagging properly puts it in front of them.

Comment: @BDL: I'd agree with that "question body" point for tags like [raspberry-pi-zero] and so on; low enough traffic tag that the [raspberry-pi] tag can probably cover all the flavours.  (I remove even that tag from questions that are actually just about ARM asm in general, not about RPi hardware specifics.  Users often tag a bunch of tags about the hardware or environment they happen to be using, but increasing the tag limit wouldn't change that problem.)

Comment: I'm failing to see how these are examples to motivate having more than 5 tags. The tags ``[c] [assembly] [x86-64] [gcc]`` plus one other tag seems to be perfectly fine for what you describe. What *other* tags would that example need to require "room to pick more than 1"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: For example, [sse] and [performance], or [sse] and [avx], or all 3 would be common cases.  And [intrinsics].  And/or [simd] if there was some relevance to generic SIMD, not just the specific x86 SIMD instruction sets.  Also maybe [avx2] + [avx].

Comment: @PeterCordes Isn't that just overspecifying it? That's up to 7 more tags, together with the initial 4 tags easily exceeding your own proposed limit of 7-8.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Many such questions don't *need* all of those, and often don't need a `[gcc]` or `[msvc]` or `[clang]` tag.  Having a limit of 8 would mean there'd be enough tags for almost all questions, and any tags that had to be left out wouldn't be very painful.

Comment: @BDL and Peter how tags help search better than a full body search that every search engine does? What value has tags in searching when the keywords are in the body of the posts?

Comment: @Braiam: How do *you* find new questions to read / answer?  I search on tags, using this [custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly+or+x86*+or+sse*+or+avx*+or+intel+or+simd+or+cpu-architecture+or+micro-architecture+or+micro-optimization+or+intrinsics+or+inline-assembly+or+low-level+or+perf+or+benchmarking+or+lock-free+or+stdatomic+or+branch-prediction+or+memory-barriers+or+instructions+nasm+gnu-assembler?sort=RecentActivity&uqlId=412&page=1&pagesize=50) which is a tag-search sorted by Activity.  I assume most people do something similar.

Comment: @Braiam: But also, sometimes when the thing I want to search on (when looking for a duplicate for example) means different things in different languages or other ambiguous hard-to-google case, I *do* use SO's search with a tag or two plus a `code:xyz` or other non-tag search term.  If your argument is "tags have no value at all", that's a very strong claim!  Is there any kind of meta consensus for abolishing them?

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't search questions to answer, I filter questions that I can know the answer of: I put the apt tag and be done with it. If I want to search for something like "dependency problems" I don't use the tags [dependency] and [problems], I search "[apt] dependency problems".

Comment: @Braiam: You're talking about searching when you have a problem yourself and want the answer.  That's one use of tags (which is still useful, especially if for example you're looking for a question about vectorizing some common problem with [avx2] instead of just [sse]).  But that use-case is easier to work around by searching on non-tag text.  Not like the problem of people looking for new questions to answer.  I assume you realize that *some* people keep an eye on activity in tags they follow so they can answer (or downvote / moderate) new questions.  That's how SO gets most of its answers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for giving some more details. Agreed that 5 tags is *very* tight for  some of these cases.

Comment: I'd like to mention that tags should reflect what a question is *about* and not what it *contains*. E.g. when a question is about a sorting algorithm, then marking it by e.g. [tag:arrays] is redundant. Marking it by [tag:algorithm] is enough. If 5 tags is a good limit or not, I don't know.

Comment: @akuzminykh: Yeah, I never add tags like `[array]`.  That's the kind of stuff the question body is for.  The kind of question I'm thinking of that might have all these tags could be something like [SIMD unpack 12-bit fields to 16-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66347928) or similar SIMD optimization problem where the actual problem being solved is described by the title, not the tags.  (Although in that case [pixelformat] is related to the problem, not the techs being used to optimize it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm afraid that you've posted good points on why the tag-limit has also downsides but they show on rather specific cases. The broad majority of questions doesn't need more than 5. I think if the tag-limit is changed, then it's via a different system of how many tags one can use instead of a simple limit on the amount. A system that covers the broad majority but also special cases. Hmm ...

Comment: @akuzminykh: Part of my point is that raising the limit (to allow special cases that need it) wouldn't hurt the broad majority much.  Unless I'm guessing wrong and lots of people will keep adding tags until the tag bar is "full", even if that means coming up with more tags that are less related to their question.  (I'm still excluding jerks that tag unrelated languages to get more eyeballs; those will always need editing.)  Maybe we could put a rep requirement on this ability, so at least experienced users could edit more tags onto new-user questions where they apply.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you should open a seperate question about this. This Q&A is kinda stuck on the "Why not more than 5." and the accepted answer is simply the answer. The attention on your post here was gone very quickly. What you write here goes beyond this simple question so it's worth a seperate question.

Comment: Many tags such as [tag:c] and [tag:assembly] encourage adding further tags if relevant to the question such as C99/C11/C17 tags or ISA-specific tags. So for a question about C11 disassembly on x86-64, you've already blown 4 tags before even applying any detailed tags to what the question is about. Now suppose my question was about disassembly differences on gcc x86-64 between C11 and C++11... Tag overflow: [tag:c] [tag:c++] [tag:c11] [tag:c++11] [tag:gcc] [tag:assembly] [tag:x86-64]. All of these tags make perfect sense on such a question.

Comment: So it is rather contradicting that we strongly encourage tag usage guidelines, that in turn often means encouraging people to add more tags. While at the same time limit the number of tags to 5 by design.

Comment: @Lundin: Yeah, that's another point in favour of allowing a higher limit.  In practice, those C/C++ language-version tags are always the first to go when other tags are more appropriate in a case like that, since GCC's or clang's optimizers don't work differently depending on `-std=gnu++11` vs. `gnu++20` unless the source means something different but can still be compiled.  So usually the language version someone happened to compile with is an arbitrary choice tangential to the assembly details of the question.