# Allow more than five tags per question in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am managing a rather small Stack Overflow for Teams community where I work and one of the users asked me why they are not allowed to use more than five tags. I replied that this is by design since the public Stack also has this limitation to ensure that [the most relevant tags are used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314115/2780791), but also that I would ask on Meta about this limitation for private Stack.

Personally I never felt the need for more than five tags, but since Stack Overflow for Teams does not have the same focus as the public one (e.g. questions can be broader), it is possible for a person to feel the need to add more than five tags:

- main product name
- vertical name
- some module name
- some layer name: [sql]
- some tag like [quick-start], [overview] when just an overview is needed and not lots of details
- maybe it is related to the [deployment] of the product
- ...

My answer to this is to simply pick the most relevant five ones, but for the private usage product I would simply make it configurable or remove the limit.

Comment: I absolutely second this. There is no reason for this to be present in the Teams version and unnecessarily limits the search filtering usability.